# Background gradient blur right hand edge

Tags: css

I have the following sash being placed over the top left corner of an image. I'm using a background gradient from black to transparent white with white text to ensure the text is visible no matter the picture uploaded. As you can see in the photo the right hand edge is abrupt and very noticeable. What I want is for that edge to have a similar gradient going to transparent as happens from top to bottom. I'm struggling to make it do that. The hard edge is even more noticeable on images which are white.

[image]

This is the css I have which has created the above:

```
.channel-info-sash {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: .5rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

I have tried using box-shadow but this makes the edge noticeable at the bottom. I have tried rotating the gradient to `135deg` but again that makes the edge noticeable at the bottom.

Is it possible to achieve the desired affect using CSS only?

**Reproducible example**
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="channel-info-sash">Today at 16:40, repeats monthly</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 750%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  position: relative;
}

.channel-info-sash {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: .5rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a radial-gradient, or multiple linear-gradients? Could you post the relevant ("*[mcve]*") HTML and CSS to reproduce the layout you're working with?

Comment: I have edited to include a reproducible example. I have tried with radial and could not achieve the effect myself. Have just tried using multiple linear gradients and that suffers with the same problem of an abrupt edge.